# JavaScript/jQuery not loading correctly automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

When the page first loads it shows all the prices until you click an option. Basically I cannot get the Java to run at start for the monthly price.

If you want to see it.

http://www.infinityhost.net/web-hosting-plans.htm

I attached the three parts of the code.

I have looked over everything a million times and can't find what makes it load the 1 month section automatically.

```js
// ______________  PRICE SWITCH

    $(window).load(function() {

        $(".price-per-period .per1").click(function() {
            $(".per1a").show();
   $(".per3a").hide();
            $(".per6a").hide();
            $(".per12a").hide();
   $(".per24a").hide();
            $(".price-per-period .per1").addClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per1").removeClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").addClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per12").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per12").addClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per24").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per24").addClass("btn-default");
        });
  
  $(".price-per-period .per3").click(function() {
            $(".per1a").hide();
   $(".per3a").show();
            $(".per6a").hide();
            $(".per12a").hide();
   $(".per24a").hide();
            $(".price-per-period .per1").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per1").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").addClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").removeClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").addClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per12").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per12").addClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per24").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per24").addClass("btn-default");
        });

        $(".price-per-period .per6").click(function() {
            $(".per1a").hide();
   $(".per3a").hide();
            $(".per6a").show();
            $(".per12a").hide();
   $(".per24a").hide();
            $(".price-per-period .per1").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per1").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").addClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").removeClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per12").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per12").addClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per24").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per24").addClass("btn-default");
        });

        $(".price-per-period .per12").click(function() {
            $(".per1a").hide();
   $(".per3a").hide();
            $(".per6a").hide();
            $(".per12a").show();
   $(".per24a").hide();
            $(".price-per-period .per1").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per1").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
   $(".price-per-period .per12").addClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per12").removeClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per24").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per24").addClass("btn-default");
        });
  
  $(".price-per-period .per24").click(function() {
            $(".per1a").hide();
   $(".per3a").hide();
            $(".per6a").hide();
            $(".per12a").hide();
   $(".per24a").show();
            $(".price-per-period .per1").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per1").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per3").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").addClass("btn-default");
            $(".price-per-period .per6").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
   $(".price-per-period .per12").removeClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per12").addClass("btn-default");
   $(".price-per-period .per24").addClass("btn-shared-checked");
            $(".price-per-period .per24").removeClass("btn-default");
        });
  });
```

```html
<span class="chooseprice">Choose price per period</span>
                <div class="btn-group price-per-period" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-shared-checked per1">1 month</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default per3">3 months</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default per6">6 months</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default per12">1 year</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default per24">2 years</button>
                </div>




            <div class="col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Easy</h3></div>
                        
                        
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <div class="per1a">
                            <h4>$2.99</h4>
                            <span class="per">1 month</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="per3a">
                            <h4>$9.00</h4>
                            <span class="per">3 months</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="per6a">
                            <h4>$15.00</h4>
                            <span class="per">6 months</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="per12a">
                            <h4>$27.00</h4>
                            <span class="per">12 months</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="per24a">
                            <h4>$54.00</h4>
                            <span class="per">24 months</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: Copy the code of click for `.per1` in the start of the 'load` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the code governing which items are shown resides in click listeners of the different buttons. When no button is clicked, none of that code is executed. All of the elements are visible in your markup, and you're not executing any JavaScript on page load that tries to change that.

Either define your starting behavior in your markup, by adding `style="display: none;"` to the divs you want hidden, or simulate a click on page load: `$(".price-per-period .per1").click();`

On another note, your code is very repetitive. You could save yourself a lot of code if the buttons and panels had some common classes, so that you could address them all in one select, and if you would extract the click listeners to one common function.

If `.per1a`, `.per2a` etc all had the class `per-a`, you could do something like this:

```
function setActivePanel(name) {
   $('.per-a').hide();
   $('.'+name).show();
}
```

Then you could call `setActivePanel('per1a')` or `setActivePanel('per2a')`, etc.

For your buttons, you could assign a single click listener:

```
$('.price-per-period .btn').click(function() {

   $('.price-per-period .btn')
      .removeClass('btn-shared-checked')
      .addClass('btn-default');

   $(this)
      .addClass('btn-shared-checked')
      .removeClass('btn-default');

   // now all you need to do is call the correct setActivePanel

});
```

For `setActivePanel`, add a data attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-shared-checked per1" data-target="per1a">1 month</button>
```

Then in your click listener, you could access it like so:

```
setActivePanel($(this).data('target'));
```

Now that you've refactored, you might find that the easiest way to solve your original problem would be to have your DOMReady listener call `setActivePanel('per1a');`

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips!